# Get only customers (with all related orders) who have at least one order with given status

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

The easiest way to explain it is by example:

```
class OrderStatus(enum.Enum):
    NEW = "New"
    TO_BE_GENERATED = "Waiting for generation"
    COMPLETED = "Completed"
    CANCELED = "Canceled"


@dataclass
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    orders = db.relationship('Order', backref='Customer', lazy=True)

@dataclass
class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id'))
    customer = db.relationship("Customer", foreign_keys=[customer_id])
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(OrderStatus))

def get_customers_with_orders(start=None, limit=None):
    return Customer.query.offset(start).limit(limit).from_self().join(Order).all(), customers.count()
```

By using *get_customers_with_orders()* I'm able to get all customers.

How to get only customers (with **all** related orders) who have **at least one** *order* with status ***OrderStatus.COMPLETED***

Comment: It would be nice if someone come up with a more generic subject

Comment: I’d suggest dumping off sqlalchemy as it’s adding a layer of unneeded complexity.  Just write a simple interface for your database and run a straight query.

Comment: Agreed. For how to provide an example, See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query